# Asp.net MVC, Web Api and AngularJS project after publishing via FileSystem, path to api rest calls doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I developed my Asp.net MVC app which also includes the Web Api. And on the client side I"m using AngularJS as below.

Everything works very well from Visual Studio 2015. Now I did a File System publish, created a web application 'MyWebApp' in IIS.

When I manually access the api calls like below, it works, returns JSON data.
http://localhost/mywebapp/api/session/uid/pwd.
But the same call made from the app via script, it throws 404 error.

```
    $http({
        url: '/api/session/' + username + '/' + password,
        method: "GET"
    })
```

I tried hardcoding the full path, it works, but I can't hard code it. How do I accomplish this?

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost/mywebapp/api/session/' + username + '/' + password,
    method: "GET"
})
```

Script from index.chtml

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getSession = function (username, password) {
            $http({
                url: '/api/session/' + username + '/' + password,
                method: "GET"
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    // success
                    //my other code goes here, which I removed to keep the question simple
                },
                function (response) { // optional
                    // failed
                    alert('failed:' + response.data);
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/mywebapp/api/session/' + username + '/' + password
```

if you are publishing to a subfolder you'll need the subfolder name on the front. A full http path may cause cross site issues. (Just an idea)